# Using jq, how can I get nested values from within nested arrays from JSON data accurately?

Tags: json, jq

I have a JSON file that looks something like this:

```
{
    "people": {
        "names": [{
                "last_name": "Smith",
                "first_names": [{
                        "name": "Bill"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Alice"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Mary"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "last_name": "Brown",
                "first_names": [{
                        "name": "Gil"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Bob"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Mary"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "last_name": "Sanchez",
                "first_names": [{
                        "name": "Gil"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Jose"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Marlena"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The output I'm looking for is:

```
Smith, Bill
Smith, Alice
Smith, Mary
Brown, Gil
Brown, Bob
Brown, Mary
Sanchez, Gil
Sanchez, Jose
Sanchez, Marlena
```

I created a jq query that looks like this:

```
jq -r '.people | "\(.names[].last_name), \(.names[].first_names[].name)"' nameFile.json | sort
```

But the output I get is:

```
Brown, Alice
Brown, Bill
Brown, Bob
Brown, Gil
Brown, Gil
Brown, Jose
Brown, Marlena
Brown, Mary
Brown, Mary
Sanchez, Alice
Sanchez, Bill
Sanchez, Bob
Sanchez, Gil
Sanchez, Gil
Sanchez, Jose
Sanchez, Marlena
Sanchez, Mary
Sanchez, Mary
Smith, Alice
Smith, Bill
Smith, Bob
Smith, Gil
Smith, Gil
Smith, Jose
Smith, Marlena
Smith, Mary
Smith, Mary
```

Obviously that's not correct, and I can kind of see why: the second expression is faithfully going through each match in the names array. But I can't see how to remedy this.

Comment: for your consideration, here's also an _alternative_ (i.e. non-jq) solution for the JSON manipulation in your question, based on a unix _walk-path_ utility jtc: `<file.json jtc -w'[last_name]:<L>P:[-1]<name>l:' -T'"{L}, {}"' -qq`. Let me know If you're interested - I can elaborate on the tool usage in a separate answer. (PS. I'm a developer of the tool)

Comment: I just got a step closer with `jq -r '.people | .names[] | "\(.last_name, .first_name[].name)' nameFile.json`. That prints the last name, followed by the associated first names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the results you want, you have to iterate over `.names` outside the loop that iterates over `.first_names`:

```
.people
| .names[]
| "\(.last_name), \(.first_names[].name)"
```

Comment: I was s l o w l y making my way in that direction, but thanks @peak for speeding it up for me :)